# IOS - Change multiple UIImages dynamically on load

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have built an IOS exersize app which has a UIImage set as a background of each UIView - The app is controlled via a CMS which feeds data about fitness sessions.

The client would like the client to be able to choose from a selection of background images that are relevant to the sport that they do - the images will be part of the app build - my question is - is it possible to change all images on mass based on a server variable?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** it is possible to change all images.

For that you have to use some webservice for getting client detail from server, based upon that you can set appropriate images.

there is two way of it,

1. you can store all images in app and based on sports load that images,

or

2.you can download new images related to sport from server.

Note: you can not change app icon dynamically.